# Generating a range of ints as strings in Java 8

Tags: java

I'll have two integers and will want to generate an array of those two numbers and all the numbers in between as strings (I know the ranges are small).

i.e. given `1004` and `1008`. I'd generate `"1004", "1005", "1006", "1007", "1008"`

I'm familiar with C# and there I'd do something like

> ```
> var start = 1004;
> var end = 1008;
> var fullRange = Enumerable.Range(start, end - start + 1)
>                           .Select(i => i.ToString())
>                           .ToArray();
> ```

I need to do this in Java 8 and have come up with

```
 String[] fullRange = IntStream.range(start, end+1)
                        .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
                        .toArray(String[]::new);
```

But I'm new to Java and wondered if there's a better / more-readable way to achieve this in Java. Am I just cramming C# into Java?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you use a stream rather than an array in the rest of your application? If so I'd simply cut off the `toArray` bit at the end. Otherwise this looks exactly like what I'd expect in Java 8.

Comment: I could possibly use a stream. The consumer of this output runs over the range to create a map. Presumably then passing a `Stream` around is like passing `IEnumerable` in C#.

Comment: @PaulD'Ambra - Approximately, although note that an `IEnumerable` can be consumed multiple times but a `Stream` can only be consumed once.  Java's closest equivalent to `IEnumerable`  is probably `Iterable`, but you'd have to provide a custom implementation to achieve that in this case. IMO this is one of the areas where the CLR's design is much better than Java's.

Answer (score 7):

`IntStream` has a [`rangeClosed` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#rangeClosed-int-int-) that allows you to omit the +1.

`IntStream.rangeClosed(start, end)` instead of `IntStream.range(start, end+1)`